# Running a flask app alongside PHP website

Tags: flask, web, backend

I have a website that runs on my linux server(apache) in the folder /var/www/html. I also have a flask app that runs in the folder /var/www. On my website there is button which should send a special string to the flask app. The problem is can not make the request. The flask app runs on localhost/5000(server ip/5000), but requests never reach the flask app(checked with some print statements).

What I have tried:

Cheked the port 5000(netstat -tuln | grep 5000):

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Disabled firewall:

```
enter code here
```

Allowed all origins:

```
CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

Allowed all ips:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

This is my flask app logic:

```
@app.route('/api/data', methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    print("Start")
    

    data = request.get_json()...
```

This is my javascript logic:

```
 try {
        const response = await fetch('https://mywebsite:5000/api/data', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!